# How to activate in app purchasing in Flutter iOS

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, in-app-purchase

I have my flutter app with in app purchasing in it. I did filled in the appstore connect details, uploaded my app build and got the details over in the in app purchasing page filled but it says ready to review. I can't submit the in app purchasing from the in app purchasing page in the appstore connect. I thought I will publish the app and it will get reviewed with it but apple rejected my app due to the missing in app purchasing functionality in the app. How can I get the in app purchasing connected in my flutter ios app I have done the work over android side my app is live but over ios I don't have any experience please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't activate in app purchasing yourself or there's no such thing. When you upload a your app to appstore connect and fills up the in app purchasing details correctly it gets reviewed for a short time which can be 1 hour to 3 days in this period there will be yellow dot saying waiting for review in your app purchasing section. Make sure SKpayment is must there and your localization is properly filled.
After reviewing period the app turns green and says ready to submit only then you have to submit your app for review and only then the in app purchasing to select for releasing pops up too if you don't select it then apple won't be reviewing your in app purchasing and you are again going to have your app rejected.